# Rsync is skipping encrypted (but mounted) home directory

Tags: rsync

I have two user-home-directories in `/home/`, `/home/user1` and `/home/user2`, whereas `user1` is encrypted (using ecryptfs) and `user2` is not. If I use `rsync` like this (invoked as `user1` which is a `sudo` user)

```
sudo rsync -avX -x --compress-level=0 --stats -h  --exclude-from=excludelist --numeric-ids --link-dest=/remotpath/current/home /home/ user@host:/remotepath/incomplete/home/
```

and `excludelist` just contains

`- .Private`

It skips `/home/user1` completely and backs up only `/home/user2`.

If I remove the exclude-option same problem (but also transfers the encrypted content in `.Private`).

Any idea, what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without the `-x` switch. Per the rsync man page `-x, --one-file-system   don’t cross filesystem boundaries`. I assume your encrypted FS is different than the root FS.

Comment: All partitions are `ext4` and entire `/home` is in one partition. Is this due to some fuse things with ecryptfs? I don't really understand. But it seems to solve the problem thanks.

Comment: fuse may be a user space filesystem, but it still seems to effect filesystem bounderies. I've run into similar user-space-fs issues with `ncdu` so I figured it might apply.

Comment: @student `/home` is two filesystems: the filesystem on the partition mounted on `/home`, and the ecryptfs filesystem mounted on `/home/user1`. “One filesystem” means just that, not “one filesystem plus any ecryptfs filesystem that may be mounted underneath it”.